# Error while starting Apache airflow worker - OSError: [Error 31] Too many links :

Tags: python, airflow

I trying to start the airflow worker with celery backend, while doing this I am using below command -
airflow worker
Now my celery connection is getting established but its throwing error as OSError: [Error 31] Too
many links /tmp/pym-565838

```
Error logs :
File "/billiard/3.6.1.0/lib/billiard/heap.py" line 79 in __init__
dir=util.get_temp_dir()
File "/core/python/3.7.5-0/exec/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py" line 366 in mkdtemp
_os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
OSError: [Error 31] Too many links /tmp/pym-565838
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604215/python-error-oserror-errno-31-too-many-links
I think it could be helpful

Comment: No it's not useful actually, I tried that before logging this issue here.

Comment: Anyone know how can I start multiple airflow workers on different machines? As I am facing above issue so